# Telegram bot api limit of incoming updates

Tags: api, telegram-bot

I was testing the Telegram bot api in order to get updates using

https://api.telegram.org/bot<tokenOfBot>/getUpdates

However, I realized I can get only 100 updates, and other ones don't appear.
Is there any way to get the rest of my updates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use the `limit` parameter to control how many updates you received. However, according to the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates):

> limit: ... Values between 1—100 are accepted. Defaults to 100

That means you cannot receive more than 100 updates at a time.

If you want to receive newer updates, you would have to acknowledge the older updates, so the server won't give you the same old messages over and over. Pay attention to `update_id`. For example, if you have received an `update_id` of 999, next time you call `getUpdates`, you should use:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getUpdates?offset=1000
```

This way, the server knows you have received `update_id`s below 1000, and will not give the same old messages over and over.

Comment: Your explanation was very clear, and my project now works perfectly.
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: To me this allowed_update parameter is not working at all. I've used ?limit=1 (which is not working) also tried,  allowed_updates='callback_query' and ?allowed_updates=['callback_query'] (but nothing worked)

Comment: first time it worked (i used in first attempt `offset=0`, then `offset=<update_id + 1>`) but after few days i started getting `{"ok":true,"result":[]}` group chat history updates always; i'm trying use `getUpdates()` without `update_id` and with `update_id` which was equal to the last update_id in the group history but every attempt receive empty list

Comment: how do we acknowledge older updates?